# Deployment solution for SVN or TFS

Tags: svn, deployment, tfs, mercurial

ASP.NET development.
workstation OS: Win XP
web hosting OS: Win server 2003

I am looking for a source control + deployment solution. Some people use 
Mercurial ([TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) + [Visual Studio plugin](http://visualhg.codeplex.com/)) & [GO](http://studios.thoughtworks.com/go-agile-release-management/). I was wondering if there's a good bundle for SVN or TFS. Since TFS is already integrated in Visual Studio, I just need a deployment tool. While for SVN, I need both VS plugin and deployment tool. For deployment tool, hope it's like GO, has one button click to deploy capability. Can the community recommend some popular or industrial standard setup? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're just using ASP.NET scripts, then you can simply install them to the right place by doing a checkout of your SVN files onto the web server, and then can update all the files by just running 'svn update' on the server. Simple and easy. An alternative is to overwrite the server files by exporting the files from the repo onto the server to keep them up to date. The first way has the benefit of only transferring changed files so its quick.

If you want to go the full-deployment route, GO is an option and there are plenty of other ALM products to choose from.

An alternative to all that is to use a continuous-integration build server, like [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). Hudson can build after checkins and keep 'artifacts' (ie packages of releases) that can then be deployed using something like [deployment plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Deploy+Plugin).

BTW, there is nothing that has a 'one-click to deploy capability' you will spend weeks, if not months, getting it all set up *just* right, and then don't do anything to your code or you'll have to go back and do some more setting up and configuration. These things can be really useful, but they are not easy options to solve whatever problems you have with release management.